# Databricks: Only one streamingContext may be started in this JVM issue not resolving

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, databricks

I'm trying to run a streaming job in databricks notebook on spark 2.4.5 version. Trying it with not using checkpointing. Tried every possible solution but unable to get active streamingContext and everytime.
The job re-attempts to run the job while testing, but the standard coding pattern above, fails with the exception (also expected): "Only one StreamingContext may be started in this JVM. Currently running StreamingContext was started atorg.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start".

So which spark streaming coding pattern should I use to be able to automatically re-run streaming jobs, stop the old streaming context and start a new one without having to restart the cluster and, ideally, without restarting the spark context?

[image: databricks notebook snapshot here]